# Android studio Changes done with layout is not reflecting in the app?

Tags: android-studio

I just created a layout using drag and drop it was not so correct, so later i erased the code and wrote all the layout code using XML code in relative layout, but even now it's displaying the previous layout which was created using drag and drop but preview works fine but app layout is displaying previous layout.

Tried clean project,rebuild etc..

Answer (score 0):

Problem was when i pressed a fix tip(for an error) it created the same layout file activity_main.xml (v-24) and both were having same name